# What will be the effect of changing the order of the filters on the sound coming from each speaker in my audio system?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, sound

What will be the effect of changing the order of the cross over filters on the sound coming from each speaker in my audio system?

Comment: The order? Do you mean the normal usage of order when applied to filters i.e. 1st order, 2nd order etc.. Or, do you mean which filter comes first in a cascaded chain of filters? Amend your question to clarify this detail AND show technical details about the filter frequencies. Don't add details as comments.

Comment: What are "the filters"? Are you talking about crossover filters in the loudspeakers? I suggest you read up on filters and learn what the order of a filter means. How that will affect the sound is difficult to say, part of the "sound" of a speaker is determined by the crossover filter. Use the **Edit** function to add this information to this question.

Comment: Hard to answer questions without some information.  Please edit your question.  The title is the teaser, while the editable part should provide relevant details.  As it is now with the tags (op-amps), I agree with Andy.

Answer (score 0):

Big difference. You cannot put a LPF after a HPF nor the reverse.  These need to be parallel from source. Cascading filters also depends on the source impedance Z(f) and load R.